# Checkbox is always checked whatever I choose

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

Hello I am building a form with 1 checkbox. The rest of the form fields work fine but whether the checkbox is checked or not the value is always 'on'.

My code:

```
<input  id="checkbox_<?=$row['csid'];?>" type="checkbox" <?php if($row['feedbackVisible'] == 'yes') { echo "checked='true'";}?> >
```

and how i get value with jQuery:

```
var review_visible_website = $('#checkbox_'+ modalId).val();
```

The checkbox starts checked but if i uncheck it, it still gives me value 'on'. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you see it as checked?

Comment: i can see it as check but when i uncheck it it still gives me value as on

Comment: What gives you the value as on?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I check if a checkbox is checked?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901712/how-do-i-check-if-a-checkbox-is-checked)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here are few ways you can test a check box with JQuery

```
// First method - Recommended
$('#checkbox').prop('checked')  // Boolean true

// Second method - Makes code more readable (e.g. in if statements)
$('#checkbox').is(':checked')  // Boolean true

// Third method - Selecting the checkbox & filtering by :checked selector
$('#checkbox:checked').length  // Integer >0
$('#checkbox:checked').size()  // .size() can be used instead of .length

// Fourth method - Getting DOM object reference
$('#checkbox').get(0).checked  // Boolean true
$('#checkbox')[0].checked      // Boolean true (same as above)
```

Comment: first method is the best! my problem was that i was checking the value with `.val` so it was always the value, no matter if checked or not. Thank you Charlie!

Answer (score 3):

Another way using javascript you can do like this:

```
    if( document.getElementById('checkbox').checked == true ){
        // checked
    }
    else{
        // not checked
    }
```